# Why is the python debugger throwing a ValueError before reaching my script?

Tags: python, spyder, pdb

When I try to debug a python script in the Spyder IDE using an exception is raised long before the debugger gets to my script.  In spyderpdb.py near line 765 I get a ValueError reported.  The full trace back is

```
debugfile('E:/anaylsis_scripts/measure_{0}_test_analysis/comparison_to_golden_measurement.py', wdir='E:/anaylsis_scripts/measure_{0}_test_analysis')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11140/1829221852.py", line 1, in <module>
    debugfile('E:/anaylsis_scripts/measure_{0}_test_analysis/comparison_to_golden_measurement.py', wdir='E:/anaylsis_scripts/measure_{0}_test_analysis')

  File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 607, in debugfile
    enter_debugger(

  File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spyderpdb.py", line 765, in enter_debugger
    code = code_format.format(repr(filename))

ValueError: cannot switch from automatic field numbering to manual field specification
```

I am expect the debugger to run and throw exceptions in my script not from the inner workings of my IDE.

I am running:

- Spyder version: 5.1.5 None
- Python version: 3.8.12 64-bit
- Qt version: 5.12.9
- PyQt5 version: 5.12.3
- Operating System: Windows 10

Comment: Most likely because your path has `{0}` in it, and Spyder is mistaking that for a format specifier. Looks like a bug, but I've never used Spyder so not sure.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it.  If you want to put that in as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Sure, answer posted.

Comment: As suggested find the issue here https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/17224

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely happening because your path has `{0}` in it, which is a valid Python format specifier, and Spyder is mistakenly treating it as such. This looks like a bug in Spyder, you could consider [reporting it](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/troubleshooting/submit-a-report.html).